# How to return Json as part of my view in C# MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json, linq, datatables

My question is: **How can I combine the two of these action results into one?** There really seems no point in having the first one only to do one line. But I cant see a way out. Any ideas would be appreciated. The remaining I provide for background.

I am trying and successful in returning a partial view with the Json results I require but I am using two ActionResults of the same name (one with parameter one without) to achieve this. If I continue in this manner, I will have to repeat all my ActionResults twice. The problem I have with this is that the first action result does nothing more than literally this:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult MyResults()
{
    return PartialView();
}
```

That is used to return the view. Within the view I have some JQuery/Ajax which in turn calls another action result of the same name but with parameters. This action result effectively populates a Json object which is then parsed and rendered into the view above as a table. Effectively this actionresult does all the work. It looks something like:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult MyResults(DataTablePrameters param)
    {
         //Get the full list of data that meets our needs
        var fullList = _myResultsRepository.GetListByID(Id);

        //Count the records in the set
        int count = fullList.Count();

        //Shorten the data to that required for the page and put into object array for Json
        var result = from r in fullList.Skip(param.iDisplayStart).Take(param.iDisplayLength)
                     select new object[]
                     {
                         r.field1,
                         r.field2,
                         r.field3
                     };

        //Return Json data for the Datatable
        return Json(new
        {
            sEcho = param.sEcho,
            iTotalRecords = param.iDisplayLength,
            iTotalDisplayRecords = count,
            aaData = result
        });
    }
```

Those of you not familiar with it, will not be aware that I am using DI/IOC and for brevity I have not included the details of this. But that is not my question. Also the above code used Datatables from the following site:

http://datatables.net/index

Which are actually quite good. And again, using all the above, my code works well. So I don't have problems with it. I know its somewhat inefficient because it loads the resultset into a variable does a count, then skip...take and so on but again, it works and this is not my question.

So again my only question is, **how can I combine the two of them into one view**. There really seems no point in having the first one only to do one line. But I cant see a way out. Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: I wanted to explain to readers in the future, that this question as is, mislead people answering to assume I incorrectly wanted to remove the HttpPost/Get attributes which was not my intent, nor my recommendation. So my code is in fact the correct way to do it. While I did get a solution working based on the answer accepted. Readers are advised to look carefully into the security issues of doing this. As the accepted answer suggested, it is better to leave things as they are because it prevents opening security holes that you have to program around to fix. Essentially why fix whats not broken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the separation of POST and GET access is not desired with just one action left, wouldn't just making "param" optional do the trick?

```
public ActionResult MyResults(DataTablePrameters param = null) {
  if(param == null)
    return PartialView();

  // Repository action...

  return Json([...]);
}
```

Comment: I very much dislike people voting questions or answers down without providing an explanation, so I voted you back up. I am getting the following error when I do this: "This request has been blocked because sensitive information could be disclosed to third party web sites when this is used in a GET request. To allow GET requests, set JsonRequestBehavior to AllowGet." I checked it out, and added it, but it doesn't change anything. Also there were some security issues that conserned me with enabling AllowGet as the message suggested. Can you suggest any alternatives. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Adding JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet should help. My test code is the same as above, only changed the type of param to String and the final line to return Json(new { Value = param }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet), which runs without error. On security: Sure, there is a reason why JsonResult does not allow GET by default. You can check the Request.HttpMethod to ensure POST before returning the JsonResult.

Comment: Admittedly, the solution I provided may not look absolutely clean, and there may be concerns, perhaps best addressed already in the original answer. Personally, I don't mind the different actions in your original solution, and I would stick with them for several reasons, maintainability being one, separation of concerns being another, but I did not want to judge what you are attempting with limited information. I agree that if anyone think my way is bad in approach, they should let me know why, so that I may better myself. Thanks for voting me back up.

Comment: I agree. My question probably encouraged the removal of the HttpPost/Get attributes. Actually, I completely forgot about their use in MVC and so you are right that I should not be combining them. When I leave them separate everything works and not that you reminded me of their importance, I understand why. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `[HttpPost]` and `[HttpGet]` attributes from the `ActionResult` you want to use.

Check the validity of your fields contain in `DataTablePrameters param` like :

```
public ActionResult MyResults(DataTablePrameters param = null) {
    if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(param.sEcho) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(param.iDisplayStart) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(param.iDisplayLength))
        return PartialView();

//Do something

return Json(...);
}
```

In your view, you can still use the `type:"POST"` into your `$.ajax()` with the `url:"/YourController/MyResults"` like you already do i supose.

Comment: I am getting the following error when I do this: "This request has been blocked because sensitive information could be disclosed to third party web sites when this is used in a GET request. To allow GET requests, set JsonRequestBehavior to AllowGet." I checked it out, and added it, but it doesn't change anything. Also there were some security issues that conserned me with enabling AllowGet as the message suggested. Can you suggest any alternatives. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: My advice is, used the JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet to make your application work AND to secure it, use HTTPS for page with critical data.

Comment: As explained with the other answer. My question did mislead people into thinking I wanted to remove HttpPost/Get. I forgot about their purpose and as part of another question, I didn't want to modify too much code to carry on paging. The problem is, that if I was to go down the route you suggest here, I would have to modify a lot of stuff anyway. So for this reason, I found the other answer more helpful and so accepted it. However, +1 as thanks for your help.